# Running external process, waiting for the program to end, getting exitcode and keeping console open?

Tags: c#, process, cmd

I want to run a couple of programs one by one, but sometimes i want to keep their console window open to see the messages/errors

Is there any possibility to run `cmd.exe /K anotherProgram.exe`, wait until anotherProgram is finished (`WaitForExit()`) and get anotherProgram's exitCode? Or maybe I can keep console open in other way than running it from `cmd /K`?

Comment: do you mean, leave the console window open so the user can read the output?

Comment: It's possible to capture the output of the console window, so you don't need to keep it open.

Comment: Yep, I wanted to keep console window open, because I thought it required less code than capturing output and presenting it somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the output and errorstream of the console program to get the messages / errors.
And that way you can get the exit code of the program too.

Take a look at the events available in the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)-class:

[Process.OutputDataReceived Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) ==> use this to capture the standard output messages

[Process.ErrorDataReceived Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.errordatareceived.aspx) ==> use this to capture the error messages

[Process.Exited Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) ==> use this to get the exit code

Following is an example regarding formatting a drive (without exceptionhandling and argument-testing) where the console window is not visisble and the output and errorstream is captured and shown in messageboxes.
The exit code is also checked on exiting the process.

```
private Process formatProc;

Private void DoFormat(string driveLetter) 
    this.formatProc = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                FileName = "format.com",
                Arguments = string.Format("/FS:FAT {0}: /V: /Q", driveLetter),
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            },
        EnableRaisingEvents = true
    };

    this.formatProc.OutputDataReceived += this.ProcOutputDataReceivedHandler;
    this.formatProc.ErrorDataReceived += this.ProcErrorDataReceivedHandler;
    this.formatProc.Exited += this.ProcExitedHandler;

    this.formatProc.Start();
    this.formatProc.BeginOutputReadLine();
    this.formatProc.BeginErrorReadLine();
}

private void ProcOutputDataReceivedHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Data);
    }
}

private void ProcErrorDataReceivedHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Data);
    }
}

private void ProcExitedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var exitCode = this.formatProc.ExitCode;
    var message = string.Empty;
    switch (exitCode)
    {
        case 0: 
            message = "Format done.";
            break;
        case 1:
            message = "Format failed. Incorrect parameters were supplied.";
            break;
        case 4:
            message = "Format failed. A fatal error occurred.";
            break;
        case 5:
            message = "Format ended by user.";
            break;
        default:
            message = "Format failed. ExitCode = " + this.formatProc.ExitCode;
            break;
    }

    this.formatProc.Dispose();
    MessageBox.Show(message);
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned above in the comments, I didn't want to capture output, but I see it is the only method, so I'll mark it as an answer. Thanks.